# Keyword redirect from any subdirectory using RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, keyword

My server log shows that visitors to my site often type common keywords that result in 404's, and I would like to redirect some of those keywords to meaningful pages in my site.

My **.htaccess** file currently contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^download.*$ https://mydomain.jp/jp/download.html [R=301,L,QSA]
```

So if someone types `mydomain.jp/download` or `mydomain.jp/downloads` in their browser, they will be redirected to `mydomain.jp/jp/download.html`.  The problem is that I want to redirect "download" and "downloads" keywords *regardless of the subdirectory* they may follow.  For example, I would want to redirect all of the following cases:

```
mydomain.jp/jp/downloads
mydomain.jp/jp/download
mydomain.jp/jp/products/download
mydomain.jp/jp/A/B/C/downloads
```

But that is not all.  I have two language versions of my site, with English being entirely contained in a `/en/` subdirectory, which has it's own language version of the downloads page.

So I want to redirect keyword searches for "download" or "downloads" to my English language download page (`https://mydomain.jp/en/download.html`) **only** when either of those 2 keywords are used after any subdirectory under `/en/`, such as:

```
mydomain.jp/en/downloads
mydomain.jp/en/products/download
mydomain.jp/en/A/B/C/downloads
```

Any keyword searches for "download" or "downloads" in the root directory or in any subdirectory **other than /en/** should redirect to my Japanese language downloads page.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: If you don't mind my saying, I think your assessment is inaccurate. Users don't just add words on to web addresses to see if they work. This is likely just "zombie" bot traffic and not real people, so not worth doing this. Check the user agents and also whether the associated resources from your 404 page are downloaded (CSS etc) when the 404 is generated, as they would be with real users.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Most who type "/download" seem to be real people.  Even I myself do that on sites from time to time, and I am no hacker.  User Agents are hard to interpret though.  For example, more than 90% of all the searches, regardless of IP address, on my site for "/wp-login.php" (obviously done by hackers) show the exact same user agent in my log: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1".  The rest appear in the log as "-".

Comment: That's why I suggest to also check if the associated files are downloaded from the page, as a bot will be unlikely to do that. Did you check that? Why do you say they seem to be real people?

Comment: I believe them to be real people based on what I see in the log file; namely, what their IP address downloads from my site and how fast (as per the time stamps).  I sincerely appreciate your advice about how to avoid feeding bots, but regardless of my reasons for wanting to do it, is what I ask possible in htaccess, and if so, do you know precisely how to accomplish it?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I do know how to do it. Thanks for bearing with me on answering those queries. I'll add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you, placed in your root `.htaccess` file, and replacing your current rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^en/.*(?<=/)downloads?$ https://mydomain.jp/en/download.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (?:/|^)downloads?$ https://mydomain.jp/jp/download.html [R=301,L]
```

The second rule will not run if the first is matched, achieving your objective for that matching anything not within `/en/`.

Any problems let me know.

Comment: Many thanks for your time in writing that code.  I confirmed it works perfectly.